# Why is my fasterize function making a raster filled with 0s for my presence/absence raster?

Tags: r, gis, raster, rasterizing

I'm trying to produce a presence/absence raster from a set of coordinates. I've turned the coordinates into a polygon, but when I use fasterize it produces a copy of the template shape filled with 0s.

I think there's a problem with the line reading in the presence data (which is just a column of 1s named "yes") because there isn't an error and a raster is made, but I don't know how to fix it and I'm new to working with spatial data.

The code I'm using is:

```
paraster <- fasterize(paframe, cropbgEU,
                        field = "yes",
                        background = 0) %>% 
  mask(cropbgEU)
```

These are the details for the polygon paframe, and the template raster cropbgEU:

```
> paframe 

Simple feature collection with 2103 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1.576116 ymin: 41.1864 xmax: 28.48484 ymax: 70.51157
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
        yes                       geometry
1         1 POLYGON ((17.85235 59.86206...
2         1 POLYGON ((15.26105 59.28842...
3         1 POLYGON ((6.511416 52.38192...
4         1 POLYGON ((22.4303 60.42065,...
5         1 POLYGON ((20.73348 50.34674...
6         1 POLYGON ((21.05561 55.90442...
7         1 POLYGON ((25.47543 61.0417,...
8         1 POLYGON ((24.82326 60.19986...
9         1 POLYGON ((13.92114 53.08867...
10        1 POLYGON ((20.99356 56.31544...
```

```
> cropbgEU

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4260, 4620, 19681200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : -10, 28.5, 36, 71.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : r_tmp_2023-06-04_002524_22764_76822.grd 
names      : layer 
values     : -11.09583, 19.84583  (min, max)
```

The extent and CRS line up as far as I can tell, which seemed to be the problem in a similar question where the raster was just NAs. There was a different question using the rasterize function, but I don't know how to apply that to fasterize: calling the data with `field = paframe@data[,"yes"]` returns the error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mask': trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "sf") that is not an S4 object
```

I'm not sure if the problem could be further back when creating the polygon, but the code was:

```
paframe <- presence %>% 
  filter(yes %in% 1) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords=c("decimalLongitude","decimalLatitude"),
           crs = 4326) %>% 
  # convert to an sf polygon object by buffering the points
  st_buffer(1)
```

With the original presence dataframe looking like:

```
> head(presence)
    decimalLatitude decimalLongitude yes
26         59.86205         17.85235   1
31         59.28843         15.26104   1
95         52.38192          6.51143   1
128        60.42064         22.43029   1
189        50.34675         20.73349   1
190        55.90442         21.05563   1
```

For reference, I'm following the instructions in the blog post [here](https://amywhiteheadresearch.wordpress.com/2022/04/19/creating-presence-absences-rasters-in-2022/) by Amy Whitehead.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: So far, {fasterize} can only handle objects of class `sf` (simple features), while your *cropbgEU* has class `RasterLayer`. You could try converting the latter to an sf-object by: `sf::st_as_sf(cropbgEU)` first.

Comment: I've just tried running that line, but it comes back with the error ```Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"```. I'd thought fasterize needed a raster object for the template -- does this mean fasterize isn't going to work with these objects?